# I set the Run in VS code and stay "running"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS code, I run my code and it just shows "Running" and nothing is done.

The output I get is:

"[Running] cd "c:\Users\moham\Desktop" && gcc test1.c -o test1 && "c:\Users\moham\Desktop"test1
"

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly configure your `Code Runner` extension from the generated `JSON config` under `.vscode` folder in your workspace. Also, you might haven't focused you've opened `GitHub Authentication` output log, not the code runner's if it actually ran successfully, which doesn't seem:

If you find it hard to configure, then switch to the Terminal section and type the following command to compile and execute it manually:

```
gcc  -o main main.c  #compiling
```

than

```
./main               #executing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open manage-settings-extensions-run code configuration-**run in terminal**.
After this, the output can be shown on the terminal tab.

Comment: How does the situation? Is there any update?